# \mid, | (vertical bar), \vert, \lvert, \rvert, \divides

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What's the difference between the different vertical bars?

```
$S = \{\, x \mid x \not= 17 \,\}$
$a \vert b$ implies $a \leq b$ when $b \ne 0$
$a|b$ implies $a \leq b$ when $b \ne 0$
$\lvert x \rvert$ is always non-negative
```

[image]

Are all of these uses correct?

Comment: (Off-topic) Actually, 1|0 but 1 > 0.

Comment: Yeah, well… it's true if a, b > 0.

Comment: Divides is actually defined on negative numbers as well; 2 | -10.  @Ben Alpert had the right condition.

Of course, that's off topic from the question.  As far as that's concerned, I'm glad you asked!  The answers have been rather helpful.

Comment: \mid automatically has spacing before and after it, which  `|` does not have.

Comment: I ended up using \bigg|, which unlike other solutions provided so far, scales.

Comment: All but `\mid` scales with `\big`-like operators. See for yourself: `\bigg\vert`, `\bigg\lvert`, `\bigg\rvert`. `\mid` doesn't. I think this is better-suited as a comment.

Comment: Why not use `\textbar`?

Comment: @user75494: `\big|` produces height that is more than sufficient for some uses.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

According to `texdoc symbols`:

`\mvert` and `\mid` are identical and produce a *relation*. `\vert` is a synonym for `|` and both produce the same symbol, but should be used in the context of an ordinal, and should be used as an *operator*, **not** as a delimiter (p54, bottom). `\divides` once again produces the same symbol but should be used as a binary *“divides” operator*.

`\lvert` and `\rvert` are left and right delimiters, respectively.

Comment: I am now thoroughly confused – what is an ordinal?

Comment: @Ben The word “ordinal” in this context is copied from the `symbols` document which uses it without explanation. My guess is that it’s the usual sense: to denote a number symbol (operand) rather than an operator or a delimiter. I can’t think of a use for this, but the very similar symbol “‖” *is* used as an ordinal in standard typography, namely as the fifth [footnote symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footnote). The consequence for LaTeX is spacing: `|` doesn’t introduce any.

Comment: So when using a vertical bar as a separator in a set definition before the condition, is that a relation or an operator? I'd say it's a delimiter, but those are left or right only, not centre. Correct?

Comment: @Christian Good question. A bit of both, I’d say. No idea what’d be appropriate here. Probably `\mid` / `\mvert`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's what I went for as well. If only because `\mvert` *sounds* like the logical choice to complement the delimiters `\lvert` and `\rvert`.

Comment: An FYI for those who want to use these symbols: `\mvert` and `\divides` require the `MnSymbol` package; `\lvert` and `\rvert` require `amsmath` or `MnSymbol`.

Comment: I really dont see a use for specifying their use. Perhaps Im naive on latex but this is for visual representation - for humans - in a rendering. Its a typesetting language, not a syntactical or programming language. This isnt XML. Does Latex get used as such? Do computers need to process mathematical purpose in order to make a proper rendering? I just dont get the "should be used for" commentary.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Good LaTeX definitely uses semantic markup, same as good HTML. Why shouldn't it? At worst, you're getting the same readability benefits for the source code. At best it facilitates customisation: imagine you're modifying your document because you want to highlight all operators using a different colour, or you want to adjust spacing. If you've used the “correct” macro then you won't have to change your document contents at all, merely the style shell (i.e. a `.cls` file). Semantic markup matters.

Comment: I suppose thats true. I didnt say it didnt use semantic (or I didnt mean to say that). What my point was, was simply that there is no point to it since the end result of readability is what matters.  It didnt dawn on me that you might want to change the color of an operator, but then again I cant imagine why I would want to do that in any professional publication in the first place.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Yes, colours were an extreme example, though I’ve repeatedly stumbled across cases where I wanted to customise something that I had previously never thought of. The main point in this particular case, I guess, is spacing. That, and LaTeX code readability, which matters regardless.

Comment: How do these commands work with respect to sizing, e.g. `\big` or `\middle`?

Comment: @SophieAlpert In the TeXbook 'ordinals' aren't referred to as such; Knuth calls them 'Ord' atoms, for 'ordinary (symbols)'.

Comment: `\divides` is a relation, not operator. It is thus identical to `\mvert` and `\mid`, not to `\vert`.

Answer (score 45):

Another option which was not mentioned in any of the comments above is:

```
F=\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{\hat x_{k-1}}
```

[image]

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Been searching for this answer for way too long, should be higher on the list!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 44):

This is similar in spirit to qbi's answer.  Let me quote from the guide to the `amsmath` package (the document known as `amsldoc`), section 4.14.2 **Vertical bar notations**:

> The amsmath package provides commands `\lvert`, `\rvert`, `\lVert`, `\rVert` (compare `\langle`, `\rangle`) to address the problem of overloading for the vert bar character `|`. This character is currently used in LaTeX documents to represent a wide variety of mathematical objects [...]. The multiplicity of uses in itself is not so bad; what is bad, however, is that fact that not all of the uses take the same typographical treatment, and that the complex discriminatory powers of a knowledgeable reader cannot be replicated in computer processing of mathematical documents. It is recommended therefore that there should be a one-to-one correspondence in any given document between the vert bar character `|` and a selected mathematical notation, and similarly for the double-bar command `\|`. This immediately rules out the use of `|` and `\|` for delimiters, because left and right delimiters are distinct usages that do not relate in the same way to adjacent symbols; recommended practice is therefore to define suitable commands in the document preamble for any paired-delimiter use of vert bar symbols:
>
> ```
> \providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert} \providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
> ```
>
> whereupon the document would contain `\abs{z}` to produce `|z|` and `\norm{v}` to produce `∥v∥`.

Comment: Adding in \left and \right then means that they have a chance of scaling correctly as well.

Comment: @daleif: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023/86 for a question about getting the right parenthesis size when the inner text isn't vertically balanced.

Comment: The package `mathtools` should be used to provide scalable versions of `\abs` and `\norm` in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, by default they're all defined to be the same bar, except for maybe some spacing differences. But LaTeX, like properly written HTML, favors semantic markup over purely functional markup - you use the command for what you *mean*, rather than just what you want to appear on the page. This way, if you decide later on that you want certain kinds of bars to look different, it's easier to change only the bars you actually want to and not mess with anything else. For example, if you want to have less space between the bars and the text in constructions like `|x|`, you can redefine `\lvert` and `\rvert` appropriately.

As qbi said, it is recommended to define a higher level of semantic markup, namely things like `\abs`, `\norm`, `\union`, `\or`, `\suchthat`, etc., to represent what you really mean in your formulas, and to use those instead of `\vert`, `\lvert` and `\rvert` directly.

Comment: they're all defined to be the same *glyph*, but the class is different; check the definitions in [plain.tex](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/base) or appendices b and f of the texbook (via the index).

Answer (score 7):

`\mid` is a relation symbol and `|` is a delimiter. As far as I know `\vert` is basically the same as `|`. For things like abslute value and norm I like to use [mathtools.sty](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mathtools.sty). This class allows to define something like `\absval{}` which translates to `\lvert ...\rvert`. This is useful when you tend to forget the closing bar. :-)

Comment: According to `symbols`, `\vert` and `|` aren’t delimiters either.

Comment: You don't need a package like mathtools to define \absval{} as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is instead of using

```
\left. ... \right|
```

one can use

```
F=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{\hat x_{k-1}}
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would have liked to add as a comment to answer above by desmond13, but cannot because of rep. If you think that the answer by desmond13 is inappropriate as well, feel free to delete both.