# Bad vertical centering in an equation

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Vertically asymmetric size variation for parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/vertically-asymmetric-size-variation-for-parentheses)

I'm trying to typeset something like the following:

```
\begin{equation}
    x = f\Biggl[\sum_{i\in\Omega} w_i\bigl(g(b_i)-b_i\bigr)^2\Biggr]
\end{equation}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Clearly the alignment is too high.  But moving to the next size smaller (`\bigg`) makes it look a little too tight.

*Is there a way to fix the vertical alignment?*

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [“Vertically asymmetric size variation for parentheses”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/vertically-asymmetric-size-variation-for-parentheses).

Comment: It looks like the question you link to is exactly what I'm looking for... perhaps the moderators should close this as a duplicate?