# Oversized parentheses around xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

This must have been asked somewhere here before, but I cannot seem to find it.

I am using `\left(` and `\right)` around an xymatrix, but the parenthesis are far too big;
[image]

with the following code;

```
 \begin{equation*}
            \left(\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d]    & B  \ar[d] \\
                      X     \ar[r]_f    &   Y}\right)
        \end{equation*}
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023/484 which was asked with this scenario, among others, in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused because the `\xymatrix{ }` sets the first line of the matrix on the baseline, the lower line goes beyond the baseline resulting in a large depth. The `\left` and `\right` macros are always centered on the baseline, and therefore are extended upwards as far the matrix goes down. Use the `\vcenter` macro to push the matrix up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \left(
    \vcenter{\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ X \ar[r]_f & Y}}
    \right)
\end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, two birds with one stone.

Comment: small nitpicking: `\valign` isn't a macro, it's a primitive.

Comment: @morbusg: I'm actually using `\vcenter` not `\valign`, but both are indeed primitives ;-)

Comment: A "pure LaTeX" solution is to enclose `\xymatrix` in a `gathered` environment. Using `\vcenter` in other cases can lead to surprises and head scratching; for example, TeX is *not* in math mode inside a `\vcenter`. Here it doesn't matter, since `\xymatrix` can be used in text mode and, most importantly, it builds a box.

Comment: `:-O` *facepalm*

Comment: +1. Works perfectly.