# Proper display of fractions

Tags: math-mode, fractions, displaystyle

Have a look at the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
 $2-\frac{2}{1-\left(\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)}$\quad
 $2-\dfrac{2}{1-\left(\dfrac{2}{2-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}\right)}$\quad
 $2-\cfrac{2}{1-\left(\cfrac{2}{2-\cfrac{2}{x^2}}\right)}$\quad
 $2-\dfrac{2}{1-\left(\cfrac{2}{2-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}\right)}$
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Evidently, the first display is not the proper way. The second and last are the same I guess. The third has a better display but there is too much space above the 2 in `\left(\cfrac{2}{2-\cfrac{2}{x^2}}\right)`. Essentially, non of the above displays satisfies, for me, a good Mathematical typsetting. Although, it may be argued that it is the default in LaTeX. I just can't get it right? Any insights? In a book I got this example from it looks like this without the excessive bold (this is a scanned image):

[image]

Comment: Related: [Vertically asymmetric size variation for parentheses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023).

Comment: And why not :  $\displaystyle 2-\frac{2}{1-\left(\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)}$

Comment: @Altermundus Nah, the part `\left(\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)` looks to compressed. Isn't it?

Comment: I'd change the title into "Improper use of parentheses". `:)`

Comment: I must confess I don't understand why you're using parentheses in the first place. Without the parentheses, the output looks perfectly readable *and* you don't have any issues with raising or lowering stuff.

Comment: What about: `$\displaystyle 2-\frac{2}{1-\left(\displaystyle\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)}$`

Comment: @Mico My teaching experience tells me that at-risk students have a difficulty in following process when typesetting my lecture notes so am using the parenthesis to emphasize the fractions in question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox{<length>}{<text>` to shift the content up as desired.

So using it to shift up the content with in the large brackets you get:

```
\[ 2-\frac{2}{1-\left(\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\displaystyle\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}$}\right)} \]
```

you get:

[image]

If you also want the `1 -`  to be aligned with the fraction's vinculum, you can apply `\raisebox` to that as well:

[image]

I personally think the above looks the best, but if you desire the last fraction in `\displaystyle` as well then the fraction size increases and the shift amount applied by `\raisebox` also needs to be increased:

[image]

### Note:

- `\raisebox` expects text as its parameter so you need to put that content within math mode.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    2-\frac{2}{1-\left(\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\displaystyle\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}$}\right)}
\]
If you want the minus sign aligned with the fraction:
\[
    2-\frac{2}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{$1-$}\left(\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\displaystyle\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}$}\right)}
\]
If you want the last fraction to be in 
\verb|\displaystle| as well:
\[
    2-\frac{2}{\raisebox{1.1ex}{$1-$}\left(\raisebox{1.1ex}{$\dfrac{2}{2-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}$}\right)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add `\displaystyle` in the inner formula

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing that out. Have corrected.

Comment: But using `\raisebox` moves the fraction line in `\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}` by the specified amount, right?

Comment: Sorry, but this is still incorrect: the last fraction should be in displaystyle too. Probably `\dfrac` from `amsmath`, or directly `\cfrac`. But perhaps also the `1-` needs to be raised, then, to bring it at the same height as the main fraction line. The output is ugly nonetheless.

Comment: This is  horrible, the fraction bar is not aligned with the minus symbol in the denominator!

Comment: @azetina: Have provided a solution if you want that aligned as well.

Comment: @Altermundus: Have fixed that as well.

Comment: The last one is probably the way to go. However, `\raisebox` doesn't need `graphicx`. And I'm having a hard time in understanding *why* one should want such a thing.

Comment: @egreg What _thing_ are you referring to?

Comment: @azetina That horrible parenthesized subformula. Maybe you have some reasons for wanting it, but I don't see which it can be. :) If you need to put that subformula into evidence, maybe enclosing it in a box with the help of the mighty `\tikzmark` could be better.

Comment: @egreg I guess that is the case but while the `\tikzmark` is a possibility I was looking for an immediate solution to the observed situation and use of the parenthesis.

Answer (score 14):

I think it's just enough to hide the depth of the inner fraction rather fall back on explicit positioning.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 $\displaystyle 2-\dfrac{2}{1-\left(\dfrac{2}{\smash{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}}\right)}$ 

\end{document}
```

---

Or this version, which uses displaystyle throughout and preserves the vertical alignment of fraction bar and minus sign by putting the brackets around the whole lower expression, and then backspacing the "1-" outside the brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


 $\displaystyle 2-\dfrac{2}{\phantom{1-{}}\left(
   \vcenter{\hbox{\llap{$\displaystyle1-{}$\kern1em}$\displaystyle\dfrac{2}{2-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}$}}
   \right)}$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: But the `\frac{2}{x^2}` is not in display mode.

Comment: well you can use `\dfrac` for the inner fraction as well, I just thought at some point you might like to let the font shrink. actually you can't (it overprints, may post a version latter, got to go now)

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, the `nath` package correctly scales the delimiters:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
   2-\frac{2}{1-(\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}})}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

More interestingly, it automatically changes the display fractions to inline fractions when you used in inline math mode:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
$2-\frac{2}{1-(\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}})}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to force one or another type of fraction when using nath package?

Answer (score 5):

The `\scaleleftright[maxwidth]{left-delim}{term}{right-delim}` macro provides scalable (not extensible) delimiters without forcing vertical height symmetry about `\frac`s.  The optional parameter is a width limiter on the delimiters.

Note that the math axis of the fraction is not altered (as it is with a `\raisebox`), so the fraction's vinculum remains vertically aligned, automatically.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\def\parenthis#1{\scaleleftright[1.5ex]{(}{#1}{)}}
\begin{document}
 $2-\frac{2}{1-\parenthis{\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}}}$\quad
 $2-\dfrac{2}{1-\parenthis{\dfrac{2}{2-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}}}$\quad
 $2-\cfrac{2}{1-\parenthis{\cfrac{2}{2-\cfrac{2}{x^2}}}}$\quad
 $2-\dfrac{2}{1-\parenthis{\cfrac{2}{2-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution from an answer of Jean Côme Charpentier on fr.comp.text.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\adjust}[2][0pt]{\mathpalette\@djn{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\@djn}[2]{%
\mbox{\raisebox{\@firstoftwo#2}{$#1\left(\raisebox{-\@firstoftwo#2}%
{$#1{\@secondoftwo#2}$}\right)$}}}  
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\[
    2-\frac{2}{1-\left(\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)}  
   \longrightarrow 2-\frac{2}{1- \adjust[-2pt]{\frac{2}{2-\frac{2}{x^2}}}}   
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]