# increasing summation size in continued fraction

Tags: displaystyle

I've got a continued fraction, where the denominator has a summation...

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ y_i = 1 - \cfrac{1}{x_i + \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(
          \cfrac{1}{x_j +\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \left (
          \cfrac{2}{x_k + \displaystyle \sum_{q=1}^{N} \left(
          \cfrac{3}{x_q-\ddots } \right)} \right) } \right)}
\]
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

I can deal with the large amounts of space at the top using this:
[Proper display of fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59747/proper-display-of-fractions)
but I'd really like to increase the size of the summations, ideally to the point that the parentheses aren't needed.

Comment: Remove the parentheses and use `\sum\limits` instead of `\displaystyle\sum`. You'll see immediate improvements. For [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3rzRT.png), I also added `\;` in front of `x_`

Comment: That doesn't increase the summation size noticeably.

Comment: check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/making-a-big-summation-sign

Comment: @Joel There's no need to increase the suze of the summation sign, that's what I want to point out: in my picture it is indeed *smaller*. Which is the reason why I commented rather than answering.

Comment: @egreg I already had the version without parentheses.  I feel the summation is too small (at least in the real-life example I have).  I'd prefer to have the summations as large as everything that is being summed.

Comment: @Joel I can't help you with that: increasing summation and integral signs is against my religion. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ y_i = 1 - \cfrac{1}{x_i + \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{N}
          \cfrac{1}{x_j +\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{N}  
          \cfrac{2}{x_k + \displaystyle \sum_{q=1}^{N} 
          \cfrac{3}{x_q-\ddots } }  } }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Are you suggesting this?

Comment: No, I suggest `\sum\limits` instead of `\displaystyle\sum`

Comment: I already have a version like this.  I'm asking if there is a way to increase the size of the summation more so that at a glance it's obvious that the x_j is part of the summation over j.

Comment: by adding a small space before the leading `$x_j$` (and thus making the fraction line a bit wider at the left) there would be a clearer separation from the sum.  that should be enough to make the intention clear.  (this is a good-looking answer, and would definitely be a form accepted by a professional copyeditor.)

Answer (score 0):

With the `\scaleleftright[max_width]{left-delim}{term}{right-delim}` macro from the `scalerel` package, symmetry of vertical height about the fraction bar is not enforced, making for a more pleasing look *in this particular case*.

With the macro, the delimiters are scaled to the vertical height of the `term`, but in this case, the maximum delimiter width is constrained to 1.5ex, which can be changed, of course.

RECOMMENDED ANSWER:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[ y_i = 1 - \cfrac{1}{x_i + \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{N}\scaleleftright[1.5ex]{(}{
          \cfrac{1}{x_j +\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{(}{
          \cfrac{2}{x_k + \displaystyle \sum_{q=1}^{N} \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{(}{
          \cfrac{3}{x_q-\ddots }}{)}}}{)} }}{)}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

WHAT THE OP ASKED FOR (NOT RECOMMENDED):

This takes the recommended answer, but places the `sum`s as the first argument to the `\scalerel{term-to-be-scaled}{term-to-be-scaled-to}` macro, effectively growing it to the vertical extent of the associated fraction.

By utilizing the `\ignoremathstyle` macro (make sure you have V1.7 of `scalerel`), math style preservation is disabled inside of `scalerel` arguments, or else the nesting of `\mathchoice`s quickly brings efficiency to its knees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2015/02/18]
\begin{document}
\[\def\maxwd{2ex}\ignoremathstyle
  y_i = 1 - \cfrac{1}{\raisebox{-18pt}{$x_i +{}$} \scalerel{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{N}}
              {\scaleleftright[\maxwd]{(}{
          \cfrac{1}{\raisebox{-11pt}{$x_i +{}$} \scalerel{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N}}
              {\scaleleftright[\maxwd]{(}{
          \cfrac{2}{\raisebox{-3pt}{$x_i +{}$} \scalerel{\displaystyle\sum_{q=1}^{N}}
              {\scaleleftright[\maxwd]{(}{
          \cfrac{3}{x_q-\ddots }}{)}}}}{)}}}}{)}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]