# \left( and \right) too big when surrounding a sum (etc.) with no superscript; exacerbated by substack

Tags: vertical-alignment, subscripts, superscripts

When I write

```
\varphi^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{p} < B \\ p \text{ prime}}} \mathfrak{p}\right)
```

I get something like this:

[image]

Apparently it's leaving symmetric amounts of room for the sub- and superscripts.  How do I get rid of all that excess space at the top?

EDIT:  It's not so clear from the closeup I posted, but here's an example of how ridiculous it looks in context:

[image]

Comment: You know that this will look awkward either way... if you push up the content, `\bigcap` will not be vertically centred on the math axis. Alternatively, shrinking the brackets without raising the internal content would make this look too low.

Comment: See the example in context above -- it would look a *lot* better if the brackets shrank just to wrap the actual ink, even if that made them asymmetric.  I'm also not married to the idea of the \bigcap being vertically centered.

Comment: It's not an actual answer, but how about moving the `_p_ prime` to the end of the equation? Something like `.../right) \quad\forall\quad p\in\mathcal{P}` where `\mathcal{P}` is the set of prime numbers of interest?

Comment: These are actually prime ideals in a ring.  I guess I could write [\mathfrak{p}] \in \Spec B instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\Big` or `\bigg`; my preference would go to the former. It's not necessary that the parentheses encompass the whole contents, they are just delimiters. Surely having them asymmetric with respect to the formula axis would be worse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\varphi^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{p} < B \\ p \text{ prime}}} \mathfrak{p}\right)
\]
\[
\varphi^{-1}\Bigl(\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{p} < B \\ p \text{ prime}}} \mathfrak{p}\Bigr)
\]
\[
\varphi^{-1}\biggl(\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{p} < B \\ p \text{ prime}}} \mathfrak{p}\biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with

```
\[
\varphi^{-1}
\mathopen{\raisebox{-1.8ex}{$\Biggl($}}\,
\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{p} < B \\ p \text{ prime}}} \mathfrak{p}
\mathclose{\raisebox{-1.8ex}{$\Biggr)$}}
\]
```

where the parentheses have been shifted down

[image]

Answer (score 7):

you can raise it but that doesn't look nice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\varphi^{-1}
\left(\array{@{}c@{}}
  \displaystyle\bigcap\\
  \substack{\mathfrak{p} < B \\ p \text{ prime}}\endarray 
\mathfrak{p}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great to me, though in context I'd like to lower the bit in parens so that the \bigcup is centered (and the parens are not).  Is there a way to do this?  (I don't understand what your code does.)

Comment: try `  \raisebox{-2ex}{$\displaystyle\bigcap$}\\` for that line