# How to write ceil and floor in latex?

Tags: math-mode

Is there a macro in latex to write `ceil(x)` and `floor(x)` in short form? The long form

```
\left \lceil{x}\right \rceil
```

is a bit lengthy to type every time it is used.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was asking questions in the wrong forum indeed!

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42271/47927

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), you could define macros `\ceil` and `\floor`, which will scale the delimiters properly (if starred):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \floor*{\frac{x}{2}} \leq \frac{x}{2} \leq \ceil*{\frac{x}{2}}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: example of using floor and ceiling]

Comment: That's neat. Didn't know about this command.

Comment: Doesn't work here. Any idea how to do it without mathtools?

Comment: Just a question: why * when using \floor? I noticed that if the * is omitted from the command, the delimiter does not resize... but why?

Comment: @Gherardo: Check the documentation of the mathtools package. It's just the way the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro works — you can also make it use a specific size if you want to: `\floor[\Bigg]{\frac{x}{2}}`.

Comment: As a minor side note, the inequality you used as an example is incorrect for all even numbers.

Comment: I do not know how the definition works, but `\lceil{x}\rceil` worked.

Comment: @Chris I don't see how the inequality is incorrect.

Comment: @Atom The post was edited after I made this comment. https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/232037

Answer (score 41):

1. You can define your own macro via the `\def` command anywhere in
   your    document. For example

   ```
   \def\lc{\left\lceil}   
   \def\rc{\right\rceil}
   ```

   and then just write `\lc x \rc`.
2. Or you use the `\providecommand` in the preamble, e.g.

   ```
   \providecommand{\myceil}[1]{\left \lceil #1 \right \rceil }
   ```

   to simply use `\myceil{x}` in your document.
3. Use an editor, like vim, that allows for defining shortcuts for
   quick and efficient editing.
4. And, finally, don't forget about **readability** of your tex document. Check out this
   [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86504/writing-readable-latex)
   for some instructive comments on how to write efficient and readable
   tex math docs.

Comment: For 1. In LaTeX you should use `\newcommand` not `\def`.  For  1. and 2. using `\left...\right` is not appropriate in a number of situations.

Comment: How does `\providecommand` differ from `\newcommand`?

Comment: @PaulWintz If the command already exists, `\providecommand` will do nothing and `\newcommand` will cause an error.  If the command doesn't exist, they are equivalent.  There's also `\renewcommand`, which will cause an error if the command doesn't already exist.  The purpose of the three commands is to make sure you realize when you're overwriting an existing command.

Answer (score 22):

This will also work fine without using mathtools.

```
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\floor` and `\rfloor` are `amsmath` commands, `mathtools` builds on top of `amsmath`, so it's no wonder, this would work even without `mathtools`. The solution with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` shows better spacing however. Perhaps you should elaborate on your answer and show some screenshot and a full example, not only fragments of code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` are in core LaTeX.  `\floor` is not defined in `amsmath`.  The `\DeclaredPairedDelimiter' is good, but in comparison to the `\newcommand` above it mostly provides an easy way to change the code when a different size is required.

Answer (score 20):

There is no need to use `mathtool` here:

```
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
```

is better than `mathtool`.

Comment: I think this is a comment to one of the previous answers, not an answer...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147972)

Comment: @Bobyandbob This most certainly answers the question. It might not be a very good answer (that is certainly my belief), but there should be little doubt that this is an answer to the question asked above.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the sentiment that the approach here is better than `mathtool`. The `mathtool` approach allows for automatic scaling (which should be used with care, if not avoided at all, because it can give sub-par results in certain cases, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108625/35864) - could not find a better example) and manual specification of fence size.