# How to prevent overstretching of brackets?

Tags: brackets

With a tall equation like the following, using simple `(` and `)` gives brackets that are too small, and using `\left(` and `\right)` gives ones that are ridiculously big:

[image]

`a+b\left(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)}_{h(x)} +g(x)\right )`

I need the brackets to stretch in a way that takes into account my equation may not be distributed evenly across vertical space - e.g. the above case is very bottom-heavy.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023/86 as I think it address the same problem.  Do any of the answers there help?  If not, it would help to understand what doesn't work with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the \big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg variants:

```
\big(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)}_{h(x)} +g(x)\big)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not rely on `amsmath` package, use `nath`.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
a+b\left(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)}_{h(x)} +g(x)\right )
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]