# Brackets around a sum that has no top limit

Tags: math-operators, delimiters

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\[ \mathcal{F} \left\{ \sum_j e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t} \right\} \]

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: sum in brackets]

The sum only has a limit at the bottom, but the bracket size is calculated as if it had both limits, leading to a lot of unneeded space at the top. Is there a way to make the brackets wrap only the bottom limit?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, as I've always seen the brackets extend symmetrically (and I assume you don't want to change the baseline inside the brackets).

Comment: For "fences" (parens, brackets, braces, etc) around a display-mode sum or product symbol, Knuth recommends *not* using automatic sizing via `\left` and `\right` directives; instead, he recommends using "manual" sizing via `\biggl` and `\biggr` directives.

Comment: related: [How to prevent overstretching of brackets?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118113/579); also [Big Parenthesis in an Equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38868/579)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, as the braces are placed symmetrically with respect to the formula axis (running at the vertical center of the summation sign).

Use `\Bigl\{` and `\Bigr\}` or, if too small, `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}` instead of `\left\{` and `\right\}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{F}\Bigl\{\sum_{j}e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t}\Bigr\}
\]
\[
\mathcal{F}\biggl\{\sum_{j}e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t}\biggr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like this is the only way that will not interfere with spacing from the surrounding text.

Comment: @KrzysztofKosiński The first, with `\Big` is the same as jhor's with `\phantom`, but takes into account the vertical space. Unfortunately, there are many shortcomings in `\left` and `\right`, which should be used with care. If you look closely, your formula has also an unwanted space between the F and the opening brace.

Comment: The extra space before brackets made by `\left` and `\right` can be removed by using the `mleftright` package.

Answer (score 11):

You can vertically center the sum this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\mvcenter}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle #1$}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\[
  \mathcal{F} \left\{ \mvcenter{\sum_j e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t}} \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of output]

I would use it with care: you have symmetry now, but the inner formula baseline is different then.

Comment: This is simply horrible. ;-)

Comment: @egreg It could be worse, such as complicated horrible. ;-)

Comment: I think this is the best, compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Two other solutions, which IMO are neither better nor worse in the technical point of view, is the combination of `\smash` and `\vphantom`, or the `\textsyle` typesetting :

```
\[ 
\mathcal{F} \left\{ \vphantom{\sum}\smash{\sum_{j}} e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t} \right\}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\mathcal{F}\Big\{ \textstyle\sum_{j} e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t}\Big\}
\]
```

where the base line of `\mathcal{F}` remains the same as that of the `\Sigma`.
[image]

EDIT : If you are not happy with this, you can put `j` on the line by using `\sum\nolimits_{j}`.

For further fine tuning of the delimiter height and of the equation height, you can load the `calc` package and define the macro :

```
\newlength{\hhh}
\newcommand{\mstrut}[2][2]{%
\settototalheight{\hhh}{$\displaystyle #2$}%
\rule[-0.5\hhh*\real{#1}+0.5ex]{0pt}{#1\hhh}%
}
```

drawing an invisible rule the height of which is the one of the mandatory argument multiplied by optional one (set to 1 by default). With this macro, and the code

```
\[ \boxed{
  \mathcal{F} \left\{\mstrut[0.7]{\sum_{j}} \smash{\sum_{j}} e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t} \right\} 
  \quad\text{or}\quad
  \mathcal{F} \left\{\mstrut[0.9]{\sum_{j}} \smash{\sum_{j}} e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t} \right\} 
  \mstrut[2]{\sum_{j}}
} \]
```

we get:
[image]
EDIT : suppressed the `\vphantum` in the above code, because it's super seeded by the `\mstrut`.

where the `\mstrut` thickness is set to `1pt` for demonstration purpose, and the box  materialize the upper and lower limits of the equation.

By this way, choosing the proper value int `\mstrut[`**?**`]{}` you control both the size of te delimiters and the verical spacing...

Comment: I like the first solution with `\vphantom`, but it seems that the displayed equation now has too little spacing from the text below it. Using `vspace` doesn't seem to work, because it looks like it adds an empty paragraph below the equation. Is there a way to add a little bit of space at the bottom?

Comment: I explain in the EDIT how two fine tune everything

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} \left\{\sum_{j}\nolimits e^{j^{\exp 2}+i\det U - 1}\right\} = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It just makes the indices not-exactly-limits as in they are not at top and at the bottom but instead at the corner, so that the fourier transform only knows about the sigma,  not the indices.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `\raise` or `\lower` command to move the brackets.:

```
 \[ \mathcal{F} {\lower4.5pt\hbox{$\bigg\{$}} \sum_j e^{-2i\pi\nu_j t} {\lower4.5pt\hbox{$\bigg\}$}} \]
```

Thus the brackets contains their arguments without too much space above, but now you have not a symmetric formula: if you add a set operator after `\mathcal{F}`, it will be aligned with this glyph, not with the centre of the bracker.