# How can I force \left, \right delimiters to automatically (!) have the same size despite line breaks?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

This code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
    z = \left( a + b + c \right. \\ 
        \left. + \frac{d}{e} \right)
\end{split} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

The two delimiters have different sizes. A common trick to obtain matching sizes is to use `\vphantom` like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
    z = \left( a + b + c +\vphantom{\frac{d}{e}}\right. \\  
        \left. + \frac{d}{e} \right)
\end{split} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

However, such an approach

- becomes rapidly **complex** as the number of line breaks increases;
- is **not maintainable** at all (because, if a line's contents change, the argument of `\vphantom` may have to be modified as well to obtain the desired output).

---

Alternative approach 1: manually size the delimiters (using `\big` and the likes). Sadly, that's not very maintainable either.

Alternative approach 2: using some math environment provided by the `breqn` package, which allows for line breaks between two `\left`/`\right` delimiters and takes care of delimiter sizing. However, I'd like to stay away from `breqn`, if possible.

---

Can you think of a way to make associated `\left`/`right\` delimiters to automatically have the same size despite line breaks, without (explicitly) using the `\vphantom` trick? Ideally, the solution should work for multiple nested pairs of delimiters. For example, in the following, the inner delimiters should have the same size and the outer delimiters should have the same size:

```
\left( \left( ... \right. \right. \\
\left. \left. ... \right) \right)
```

Comment: Why not use the fixed size delimiters, with `\Big` or even `\biggl` and `\biggr` and Co, as suggested by egreg in his answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123904/brackets-around-a-sum-that-has-no-top-limit)

Comment: You almost always get better spacing, even without line breaking if you use `\bigr(`   ... `\bigl)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I could do that, but that's not very maintainable: I'd have to manually adapt the size of each delimiter depending on the contents of each line, which may change over the course of my writing the document. I'm wondering whether a better approach exists...

Comment: It is more maintainable than using `\left` `\right` mainly because it works rather than not works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Would you discourage using `\left`, `\right` in all cases?

Comment: Hang on I'll get egreg to answer that:-)

Comment: @Jubobs `\left` and `\right` do have their uses; in my documents you can surely find them. The fact is that most of the times I see them in others' input, they are misused.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Can you think of a canonical source (on TeX.SE or elsewhere) about cases in which using `\left`, `\right` is appropriate? I can't seem to find such a canonical answer on TeX.SE. If there is none, I will ask that question.

Comment: @Jubobs Arrays and fractions are good candidates. When big operators with limits are involved, they're better not being used.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following example uses package `zref` to remember the size of the math formula in labels. Package `mleftright` is used to reduce the additional horizontal spacing by `\left` and `\right`.

Inside a complex math block, the following macros can be used:

```
\mzleft{<label>}{<left delimiter>}{<math formula>}
\mzright{<label>}{<math formula>}{<right delimiter>}
```

The macros can be nested, The `<label>` is needed to identify the pairs of delimiters. Inside the math block (math environment, ...) the `<label>` names for the pairs must be unique. After the math block `\mzreset` can be called. It frees the `<label>` names and they can be reused.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{zref-base}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{mzheight}[0pt]{\the\ht\z@}
\zref@newprop{mzdepth}[0pt]{\the\dp\z@}
\newcount\c@@mz
\newcommand*{\the@mz}{mz\the\c@@mz}
\newcommand*{\@mz@list}{}    
\let\@mz@do\relax
\newcommand*{\mzreset}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\@mz@do##1{%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname mz@##1\endcsname\relax
    }%
    \@mz@list
    \global\let\@mz@list\@empty
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\mzleft}[3]{%
  \@ifundefined{mz@#1}{%
    \global\advance\c@@mz\@ne
    \expandafter\xdef\csname mz@#1\endcsname{\the@mz}%
    \xdef\@mz@list{\@mz@list\@mz@do{#1}}%
  }{}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\@mz\csname mz@#1\endcsname
  \mleft#2%
  \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@mzleft\expandafter{\@mz}%
  }{#3}%
  \mright.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
}
\newcommand*{\mzright}[3]{%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \@ifundefined{mz@#1}{%   
    \@latex@warning{Missing \string\mzleft{#1}}%
    \mleft.#2\mright#3%
  }{%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\@mz\csname mz@#1\endcsname
    \mleft.%
    \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@mzright\expandafter{\@mz}%
    }{#2}%
    \mright#3%
  }%
}   
\newcommand*{\@mzleft}{%
  \@mzleftright lr%
}
\newcommand*{\@mzright}{%
  \@mzleftright rl%
}
\newcommand*{\@mzleftright}[5]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#4{}#5{}$}%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \begingroup
      \let\@auxout\@mainaux
      \zref@labelbyprops{#3#1}{mzheight,mzdepth}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \zifrefundefined{\@mz #2}{%
  }{%
    \dimen@=\zref@extract{#3#2}{mzheight}\relax
    \ifdim\dimen@>\ht0 %
      \ht0=\dimen@
    \fi
    \dimen@=\zref@extract{#3#2}{mzdepth}\relax
    \ifdim\dimen@>\dp0 %
      \dp0=\dimen@
    \fi
  }%   
  \copy0\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
    z = \mzleft{a}({ a + b + c +} \\
        \mzright{a}{{}+ \frac{d}{e}})
\end{split} 
\end{align*}   

\mzreset

\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
    z = \mzleft{a}{[}{%
          a + b + \frac{c}{d} +
          \mzleft{b}{(}{
            \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x
          }   
        } \\  
        \mzright{b}{
          + y}{)
        }
        \mzright{a}{
          + \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{100}i}{e}
        }{]}
\end{split}   
\end{align*}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Heiko. A follow-up: could your solution be extended to handle more than two lines?

Comment: @Jubobs: You have a left and a right delimiter, that means two lines, but arbitrary lines in between. Or do you mean to support e-TeX's `\middle`?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with `\middle`, but what I meant is that a long equation may spread over more than two lines.

Comment: @Jubobs: No problem, you can even put `\mzleft` and `\mzright` on different pages. The `<label>` of the first argument connects them. Only `\mzreset` must not occur in between, because it clears the `<label>` names.

Answer (score 8):

While I think that a) `\bigl`s are preferable, and b) biglifying your delimiters is right up there with manual hyphenation and occasional `\enlargethispage`s at the very end of proofreading, you may find that something like this makes them slightly more maintainable:

```
\newcommand\SPLIT[2]{%
  \left( #1\vphantom{#2}\right. \\
  \left. \vphantom{#1}#2\right) \\
}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{split}
    z= \SPLIT{a + b + c +}{d +\frac{d}{e}}
  \end{split}
\end{align*}
```

At least, it saves the manual repetiton of the sizing argument. I'm sure if one were sufficiently inclined, it could be extended to handle a variable number of lines, too.

Answer (score 1):

Might worth mentioning: the `nath` package supports this, although it unfortunately is incompatible with a lot of other packages.

Taken straight from the documentation, with some modifications (*):

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\[
\sin 2nx = 2n \cos x [\sin x \\
\qquad + \sum_{k = 1}^n (-4)^k
\frac{(n^2 - 1^2)(n^2 - 2^2) \dots (n^2 - k^2)}{(2k - 1)!}
\sin^{2k - 1} x]
\]
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: output]

See also:

- [Automatic left and right commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742/250119)
- [Macro for \left( and \right)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31526/250119)
- [Incompatibilities with and alternatives to nath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104532/250119)

(*): With `nath` then `$$` and `\[` are exactly equivalent. Otherwise, `$$ ... $$` is unsupported LaTeX syntax, refer to [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/250119).

Answer (score 0):

Since this question just got bumped and there is an accepted answer, I feel that it is OK to also add an answer that uses ConTeXt, since that might interest some users.

In ConTeXt formulas do by default split over lines, and there can be breaks in fences. Manual line breaks are done with `\breakhere`.

```
\starttext
\samplefile{tufte}

\startformula[align=slanted,margin=2em]
    \int_0^1 \frac{x^9}{(x^2+1)^{16}} \dd x 
    = \int_0^1 \left[
         \frac{x} {(x^2+1)^{12}}
        -\frac{4x}{(x^2+1)^{13}}
        +\frac{6x}{(x^2+1)^{14}}
        \breakhere
        -\frac{4x}{(x^2+1)^{15}}
        +\frac{x} {(x^2+1)^{16}}
        \right] \dd x
\stopformula

\samplefile{douglas}
\stoptext
```

[image: a formula that runs over two lines, split inside the fence]