# When splitting an equation, why do parentheses appear in different sizes?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have the following equation which I have split in two lines, why do I get the `(` after `=` to be smaller that the closing `)`?

```
\begin{equation}\label{testequation}
\begin{split}
d_{m}^{\sim \phi}\left(A,f\right) = \left( \mid1-Y(R)\mid^{5} -|-f(M)|^{9} +\\  \sum_{i=1;i\neq p_{i}}^{length\left(H}\right)}  \mid I\left(i\right)\right.  \left. \vphantom{\sum_{i=1;i\neq pi}^{length\left(R\right)}} -f\left(i\right)\mid^{m}\right)^{1/m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a MWE. The document doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg. Thanks for your comment. What is 'MWE`?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Does this compile for you?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124116/how-can-i-force-left-right-delimiters-to-automatically-have-the-same-size

Comment: `\left...\right` pairs may not be broken accross lines or alignment points - they produce an error message in the log file which should not be ignored.

Answer (score 9):

You should not be using `\left`...`\right` construct for things spanning over one line but fixed sized delimiters as `\Biggl`...`\Biggr`.

I've also corrected some errors and removed some more unneeded `\left`...`\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{testequation}
\begin{split}
d_{m}^{\sim \phi}\left(A,f\right) = \Biggl( \mid 1-Y(R)\mid^{5} -\mid -f(M)\mid^{9} \\
+\sum_{i=1;i\neq p_{i}}^{\text{length}(H)} \mid I(i)-f(i)\mid^{m}\Biggr)^{1/m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Further improvements can be made. BTW: probably the equation fits in one line, why using `split`?

---

### EDIT

An improved version that fits in one line and uses `\mathclap` (`mathtools` package) to reduce the spacing around `\sum`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{testequation}
d_{m}^{\sim \phi}\left(A,f\right) = \Biggl(\lvert 1-Y(R)\rvert^{5} -\lvert -f(M)\rvert^{9}
+\;\;\sum_{\mathclap{i=1;i\neq p_{i}}}^{\mathclap{\text{length}(H)}}\;\; \lvert I(i)-f(i)\rvert^{m}\Biggr)^{1/m}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Come to look at the code, I think `pi` should be `\pi` but I'm not sure, of course.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Being not sure, I haven't corrected it...

Comment: Good point. (My motivation for saying it is that the subscript for `\sum` involves `i \neq pi`.)

Comment: You should obviously correct `\mid`s with the correct `\lvert`/`\rvert`.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for the comment. I usually provide just an answer to the question in these cases, without going deeper. This time (per your comment) I've tried to provide a better solution (probably not so good) :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues with your code:

- The construct `\vphantom{\sum_{i=1;i\neq pi}^{length\left(R\right)}}` needs to be in the first line, not the second line, in order to assure equal heights of the enclosing parentheses. However, in the present case, the use of (properly delimited/terminated `\left` and `\right` will result in parentheses that are by far too large; I would recommend using the explicit sizing directives `\biggl` and `\biggr`.
- The code uses the `split` environment but doesn't provide any alignment points. A normal choice for the first line would be the `=` sign; align the second line so that it starts slightly to the right of the previous line's alignment point.
- For *absolute value* signs, do not use `\mid`, which is defined as a relational operator and therefore provides ample spacing around the vertical bars. Instead, either use simple vertical bars or, better yet, define a macro such as `\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}` to provide a more structured way of setting up the expressions.

The following code uses the `\abs` macro and shows two different outcomes: first with and then without the automatically sized outer parentheses. Observe that the second possibility doesn't require the `\vphantom` construct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{testequation}
\begin{split}
d_{m}^{\sim \phi}(A,f)
&= \left( \vphantom{\sum_{i=1;i\neq p_i}^{length\left(R\right)}}  \abs{1-Y(R)}^{5} -\abs{-f(M)}^{9} \right. \\
&\quad +\left.\sum_{i=1;\ i\neq p_{i}}^{\text{length}(H)} \abs{I(i) -f(i)}^{m} \right)^{1/m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{testequation}
\begin{split}
d_{m}^{\sim \phi}(A,f)
&= \biggl(  \abs{1-Y(R)}^{5} -\abs{-f(M)}^{9} \\
&\quad +\sum_{i=1;\ i\neq p_{i}}^{\text{length}(H)} \abs{I(i) -f(i)}^{m} \biggr)^{1/m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, if you are interested, take a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7303/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller - Thanks -- I'm definitely very interested. I ran your query code just now and was informed about 161 [!!] instances of the site bug afflicting my postings. Yikes! Much much better to find out this way, though, rather than by running a manual search. By the way, is there a way to restrict the search to just the most recent version of whatever posting/answer the algorithm finds? The reason I ask is that the algorithm appears to have "found" some answers which I had already located and fixed manually (replacing the single backslashes with double backslashes, that is).

Comment: I don't really know how to achieve this. Try asking in the chat and let know.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349797/2404343