# draw round/rectangular bracket embracing nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I know how to draw a curly bracket with the following code:

```
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5},-] (0.8,-0.75) -- (0.8,0.75);
```

But now I want to draw a round bracket, or a rectangular one. Can anyone tell how can I do this? Is it possible to do this by changing "brace" to some other values?

The result should look like:
(some pictures)

but not
{some pictures}

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below I define the styles

- `square left brace`,
- `square right brace`,
- `round left paren`, and
- `round right paren`

which yield:

[image]

### Notes:

- This is simply and adaptation of the `ncbar` style from [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}

\tikzset{square left brace/.style={ncbar=0.5cm}}
\tikzset{square right brace/.style={ncbar=-0.5cm}}

\tikzset{round left paren/.style={ncbar=0.5cm,out=120,in=-120}}
\tikzset{round right paren/.style={ncbar=0.5cm,out=60,in=-60}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, thick] (0,0) to [square left brace ] (0,4);
    \draw [red, thick] (1,0) to [square right brace] (1,4);
    
    
    \draw [blue, thick] (3,0) to [round left paren ] (3,4);
    \draw [blue, thick] (4,0) to [round right paren] (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter, how would one go about adapting this to draw horizontal braces over nodes?

Comment: See [Curly brace to insert something into an equation? Like an inverted underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47032/4301), or you should be able to adapt a solution for underbraces such as  and [How avoid that the Underbrace Outside the delimiters $| |$ appear inside the delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208164/4301).  If those don't solve your problem, please post a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Answer (score 10):

There is no equivalent to `brace` for parentheses and square brackets that is defined in the TikZ library `decorations.pathreplacing`, unfortunately.

It depends on what your use case is as to whether the following recommendation is a sensible one or not, but one possible way you might achieve something like what you want is to make use of the [`\vphantom` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124116/32888) and the fact that `(` and `[` are [delimiters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Brackets.2C_braces_and_delimiters).

Here, I put `\left(` and `\right)` in their own `node`s that are placed relative to the main `node` using the TikZ library `positioning`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (picture) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{image-a}};
    \node (left-paren) [left = of picture] {$\left(\vphantom{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{image-a}}\right.$};
    \node (right-paren) [right = of picture] {$\left.\vphantom{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{image-a}}\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to wrap an image in parantheses you can use `\rule{width}{height}` instead of `\includegraphics...` to set the desired height. I think this should be the accepted answer, because the other answer produces ugly parantheses for bigger heights.

Comment: I agree with @MaPePeR, great answer - please add their good suggestion as well.