# How avoid that the Underbrace Outside the delimiters $| |$ appear inside the delimiters

Tags: equations, delimiters

I have this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\left|\underbrace{-6rO^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)-3O^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)}_{O^1\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)}\right|
\end{document}
\]
```

Im trying to make that the underbrace appear outside the delimiter `$||$` but if I colocate the underbrace outside the delimiter, like this

```
\[
\underbrace{\left|-6rO^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)-3O^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)}_{O^1\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)\right|}
\]
```

I get an error. How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pay attention to proper nesting of braces and `\left ... \right` pairs, your second example is incorrect in this sense. Just avoid using `\left ... \right` since they are evil, and you'll be fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{\biggl|-6rO^2\Bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\Bigr)-3O^2\Bigl(\frac{G_p}{r}\Bigr)\biggr|}_{O^1\bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\bigr)}
\]

\end{document}
```

Btw, if I just change `\left ... \right` to either `\biggl ... \biggr` or `\Bigl ... \Bigr` or `\bigl ... \bigr` depending on how large delimiters I want, it's immediately obvious where is the mistake:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{\biggl|-6rO^2\Bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\Bigr)-3O^2\Bigl(\frac{G_p}{r}\Bigr)}_{O^1\bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\bigr)\biggr|}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean @tohecz with "evil" when you refer to the \left and \right delimiters?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Unfortunately there is no canonical post about it, but some insight can be found in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/left-right-across-multi-line-equation The biggest problems are: (1) incorrect spacing (can be fixed), (2) the inside of the `\left...\right` pair is a mathinner atom, which means that linebreaks are prevented, and spaces are fixed in lengths instead of being glues (allowing small stretch and shrink).

Answer (score 2):

A few possible improvements to previous (Tohecz's) solution: since you load `mathtools` (in that case, needless to load `amsmath`), you can define an `\abs`  command that can have either an optional argument: `\big`, `\Big` and the like, or a star version that implicitly adds a pair of `\left…\right`. This will result in a cleaner syntax.

You also can use the `\underbracket` command, with an adjustable thickness.

Demo:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}


    \DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\abs}[1]{\lvert}{\rvert}{\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}
    \begin{document}

    \[
    \underbrace{\abs[\Big]{-6rO^2\Bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\Bigr)-3O^2\Bigl(\frac{G_p}{r}\Bigr)}}_{O^1\bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\bigr)}
    \qquad
    \underbracket[0.6pt]{\abs[\Big]{-6rO^2\Bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\Bigr)-3O^2\Bigl(\frac{G_p}{r}\Bigr)}}_{O^1\bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\bigr)}
    \]
    \[
    \underbrace{\abs*{-6rO^2\Bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\Bigr)-3O^2\Bigl(\frac{G_p}{r}\Bigr)}}_{O^1\bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\bigr)}
    \qquad
    \underbracket[0.6pt]{\abs*{-6rO^2\Bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\Bigr)-3O^2\Bigl(\frac{G_p}{r}\Bigr)}}_{O^1\bigl(\frac{ G_p}{r}\bigr)}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need flexibility in how the brace is drawn then you could use `tikz` as well:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

% Tweak these as necessary
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}%
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{1.0ex}%  
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{0.0em}% 


\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertUnderBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{yshift=0.0cm} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = left tikzmark
    m   % #4 = right tikzmark
    m   % #5 = text to place under brace
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude}, decorate, thick, draw=blue, text=black, #1]
        ([#2]$(#4)+( \HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) -- 
        ([#2]$(#3)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$)
        node [below=\VerticalOffset, midway, align=center] {#5};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\AbsWithUnderBrace}{%
    s%               #* = draw brace on outside
    O{}%             #2 = draw options
    O{yshift=0.0cm}% #3 = optional brace shift options
    m%               #4 = content
    m%               #4 = underbrace content
}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \tikzmark{StartBraceA}\left|#4\right|\tikzmark{EndBraceA}
    }{%
        \left|\tikzmark{StartBraceA}#4\tikzmark{EndBraceA}\right|
    }%
    \InsertUnderBrace[draw=red, ultra thick, text=blue][yshift=-1.5ex]{StartBraceA}{EndBraceA}
        {$O^1\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)$}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
    \AbsWithUnderBrace*[draw=red, ultra thick, text=blue][yshift=-1.5ex]
        {-6rO^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)-3O^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)}
        {$O^1\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)$}
\qquad
    \AbsWithUnderBrace[draw=red, ultra thick, text=blue][yshift=-1.5ex]
        {-6rO^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)-3O^2\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)}
        {$O^1\left(\frac{ G_p}{r}\right)$}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to typeset only the main part without the subscript and the underbrace to get the required height of the delimiters, which can be done with `\vphantom`.

The syntax of `\dunderbrace` is

```
\dunderbrace<left><body>_<subscript><right>
```

where `<left>` is the left delimiter (in your case `|`), `<body>` is to be underbraced, `<subscript>` is what goes under the brace and `<right>` is the right delimiter.

Note that `_<subscript>` can be omitted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dunderbrace}[2]{%
  \@ifnextchar_{\dunder@next{#1}{#2}}{\dunder@next{#1}{#2}_{}}%
}
\def\dunder@next#1#2_#3#4{%
  \left#1\vphantom{\displaystyle#2}\right.\n@space
  \underbrace{#2}_{#3}%
  \n@space\left.\vphantom{#2}\right#4%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\dunderbrace|{-6rO^2\left(\frac{G_p}{r}\right)-3O^2\left(\frac{G_p}{r}\right)}
  _{O^1\left(\frac{G_p}{r}\right)}|
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your aim is that the underbrace also cover the delimiters, then it's much easier:

```
\[
\underbrace{\left|-6rO^2\left(\frac{G_p}{r}\right)-3O^2\left(\frac{G_p}{r}\right)\right|}
 _{O^1\left(\frac{G_p}{r}\right)}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose @egreg that this solution atack the problem from a point of view that can be  generalized to other cases, however it is a very complicate solution to solve my simple answer that requires a lot use of package.