# Splitting multiline equations in between of parenthesis

Tags: equations, align

I am using `align` for multiline equations and works fine but I am encountering a limitation. I have terms between parenthesis  opened and closed with `\left( \right)`. Since there are many terms between them I need to split `\right)` to the next column of `\left(`. However in this way it does not compile.

Here my example. This compiles

```
\begin{align*}

&= \sigma^2 \left(\cancel{\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}}\cancel{X^T X}   \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} + \left(X^T X\right)^{-1}X^TD^T \right)+\\
&\quad + D X \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +DD^T =\\
\end{align*}
```

and this does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &= \sigma^2 \left(\cancel{\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}}\cancel{X^T X}   \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} + \left(X^T X\right)^{-1}X^TD^T +\\
    &\quad + D X \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +DD^T \right)=\\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\left` command has to be completed by a `\right` command in the same line of the equation. So, try `\right.` in the end of the first line and `\left.` in the beginning of the second line. (dot version will print nothing but will help the commands to be complete)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use also the environment `multlined` with a different aspect.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,cancel}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{multlined}
= \sigma^2 \Bigl(\cancel{\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}}\cancel{X^T X}\left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +  \left(X^T X\right)^{-1}X^TD^T\\ 
+ D X \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +DD^T\Bigr)=
\end{multlined}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Addendum

With @GuM's comment you will have:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,cancel}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{multline*}
    = \sigma^2 \Bigl(\cancel{\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}}\cancel{X^T X}\left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +  \left(X^T X\right)^{-1}X^TD^T\\ 
    + D X \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +DD^T\Bigr)=
    \end{multline*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead ofing say `\[ \begin{multlined} ... \end{multlined} \]`, just say `\begin{multline*} ... \end{multline*}`.

Comment: Although your code works with `\Bigl( \Bigr)`, it does not with for example `\left( \right)` or `\left[ \right]`

Comment: Of course it can' t work. The multline environment is similar to splitting the equation and so you use `\Bigl(` or `\Bigr)` to compile correctly. There are many answers that justify this concept. If you need help, I'm available. I remember you that `\left(... \right)` also cause problems with the correct size of the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is to use `\left.` for opening a left brace that is not visible as well as `\right.` for a hidden right brace. So before you add `\\`, add `\right`. Then, add `\left.` as soon as you start the next line.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &= \sigma^2 \left( \cancel{\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}}\cancel{X^T X} \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} + \left(X^T X\right)^{-1}X^TD^T +\right.\\
  &\left.\quad + D X \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} +DD^T \right)=\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, wait: with this method, in general, there is no guarantee that the closing parenthesis will be the same size as the opening one.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have linebreaks between the `\left` and `\right` delimiters, because they define a group.
With `\right.` and `\left.` you can get line breaks as pointed out by koleygr and M. Al Jumaily, but the parenthesis might have different size. I recommend [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124135/194522) to get brackets with automatically matching sizes (works even with nested parenthesis).