# Related to raise to power in equation

Tags: equations, pdftex, overleaf, multline

I am trying to have raise to power in the following equation, but it gives me the error: **Missing \right. Inserted Extra \right.**

Here is the latex code for the equation:

```
\begin{multline}
    P_{out} = \left[1-\exp\biggl(-\frac{\phi}{\sigma^2_{f_m}\bar{\gamma}}\biggr) + \exp\biggl(-\frac{\phi}{\sigma^2_{f_m}\bar{\gamma}}\biggr)\cdot \\ \frac{\exp{(\delta)}}{\sqrt{(\alpha_m^{\ast})^2\sigma_{f_m}^{2}\sigma_{g_m}^{2}}}\cdot 
    \sum_{k=0}^\infty W_{-k-\frac{1}{2},0}(2\delta)\cdot \sigma_h\cdot \gamma\biggl(k+1, \frac{\gamma_{th}}{\frac{A}{\sigma^2_h}}\biggr)\right]^{M}
    \label{final}
\end{multline}
```

Note: I am using double column, IEEE format.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just replace the `\left` and `\right`? Unless you want to automatically fit the parentheses size...

Comment: Welcome. // Please provide sufficient code we can copy, compile and see your problem. Please start with \documentclass , relevant packages, your relevant content until \end{document} .

Comment: Thank you @ user202729, on removing \left and \right, the error is gone but how to adjust the parentheses size?

Comment: Most answers suggest using manual sizing [math mode - Break Large Equation Between Parenthesis Using Multline - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126735/break-large-equation-between-parenthesis-using-multline). There are some other answers in [align - Splitting multiline equations in between of parenthesis - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505468/splitting-multiline-equations-in-between-of-parenthesis) too, not sure

Comment: Ok ....thanks ....will explore it....

Comment: use of \Biggl and \Biggr solves the problem.... once again thanks to both  
user202729 and MS-SPO.