# Tree in a growing bracket

Tags: math-mode, tikz-qtree

I try to enclose my syntax tree in a growing double bracket using `\left \llbracket ... \right \rrbracket`. However, the tree always sits in the lower half and leaving the upper half blank, which is very ugly... What's more, I cannot make the angle bracket grow with the tree...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

$\left \llbracket \textbf{\Tree [.S [.S [ [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ] ] and [.S [ [.NP [.N John ] ] [.VP [.V drinks ] ] ] ] ]} \right \rrbracket$ \\
$\left \langle \left ( \Tree [.S [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ] \right ) \right \rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023/484

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to load both `qtree` *and* `tikz-qtree`. You should stick to the latter.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `baseline` option to set the baseline at the same height as the center of the picture (minus half the *x* height).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\[ \left \llbracket
  \tikz[font=\bfseries, baseline={([yshift=+-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]{
    \Tree [.S [.S [ [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ] ] and
          [.S [ [.NP [.N John ] ] [.VP [.V drinks ] ] ] ] ]
  } \right \rrbracket\]

\[ \left\langle \left(
   \tikz[baseline={([yshift=+-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]{
     \Tree [.S [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ]}
   \right) \right\rangle \]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If the trees are on the same line, they will no longer be aligned by the baselines of the original trees i.e. the baseline of the root node, as seems usual in linguistics.

Answer (score 5):

You can also either use the `gathered` environment of `amsmath` or a more low-level `\vcenter{\hbox{}}` construction: (but no clue for your `\rangle`'s)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

% here a construction with gathered and package forest for the tree
% $\left \llbracket
%   \begin{gathered}
%     \textbf{\begin{forest}
%       [S [S [ [NP [N [Ann] ] ] [VP [V [smokes] ] ] ] ] [and] [S [[NP [N [John]
%       ]] [VP [V [drinks] ] ]] ] ]
%     \end{forest}}
% \end{gathered}
% \right \rrbracket$ \\

$\left \llbracket \vcenter{%
      \hbox{\bfseries\Tree [.S [.S [ [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ] ] and [.S [ [.NP [.N John ] ] [.VP [.V drinks ] ] ] ] ]}} \right \rrbracket$ 


% with gathered:

$\left \langle \left (
    \begin{gathered}
      \Tree [.S [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ]
    \end{gathered}
\right ) \right \rangle$

% with \vcenter and \hbox:

$\left \langle \left (
    \vcenter{%
      \hbox{\Tree [.S [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ]}%
    }
\right ) \right \rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image: centeredtrees]

---

If you want to have multiple trees on same line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newbox\mytreebox
\newbox\mytreeboxwithdelim

\makeatletter
\newcommand\TreeWithDelim [3]{%
   \setbox\mytreebox\hbox{{#3}}%
   \setbox\mytreeboxwithdelim\hbox{$#1\vcenter{\copy\mytreebox}#2$}%
   \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\mytreeboxwithdelim+\dp\mytreeboxwithdelim\relax
   % in my testing, same as total height of non decorated treebox
   \leavevmode\raise\dimexpr-.5\dimen@-\fontdimen22\textfont2+\ht\mytreebox\relax\box\mytreeboxwithdelim
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}%
XX\TreeWithDelim {\left\llbracket}{\right\rrbracket}
    {\bfseries\Tree [.S [.S [ [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ] ] and [.S [ [.NP [.N John ] ] [.VP [.V drinks ] ] ] ] ]}\hfill
\TreeWithDelim {\left\langle\left(}{\right)\right\rangle}
    {\Tree [.S [.NP [.N Ann ] ] [.VP [.V smokes ] ] ]}XX

\end{document}
```

[image]

The horizontal rule is for demonstrative purposes only.

Comment: If the trees are on the same line, they will no longer be aligned by the baselines of the original trees i.e. the baseline of the root node, as seems usual in linguistics.

Comment: @cfr updated...

Answer (score 2):

This combines Forest with the new *coffins* to create a tree style

```
delimit tree={<left delimiter>}{<right delimiter>}
```

It tries to keep the baselines correct, although I am not certain that I've got this quite right, so it may need tweaking. (It worked with minimal testing, but I don't really trust it.)

Given the definition of the new style, this allows us to write

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\bfseries,
  },
  delimit tree={\left\llbracket}{\right\rrbracket}
  [S
    [S
      [
        [NP
          [N
            [Ann]
          ]
        ]
        [VP
          [V
            [smokes]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [and]
    [S
      [
        [NP
          [N
            [John]
          ]
        ]
        [VP
          [V
            [drinks]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  delimit tree={\left\langle\left(}{\right)\right\rangle}
  [S
    [NP
      [N
        [Ann]
      ]
    ]
    [VP
      [V
        [smokes]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Note that this maintains (I think!) the corrected alignment of the trees on the baseline.

[image: aligned trees]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,xcoffins}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\NewCoffin\OuterForestCoffin
\NewCoffin\InnerForestCoffin
\forestset{%
  delimit tree/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      draw tree stage/.style={
        for root'={
          draw tree box=0,
          draw tree,
          TeX={%
            \SetHorizontalCoffin\InnerForestCoffin{\box0}%
            \SetHorizontalCoffin\OuterForestCoffin{%
              $#1 \TypesetCoffin\InnerForestCoffin[vc,l]#2$%
            }%
            \TypesetCoffin\OuterForestCoffin[t,l](0pt,(\CoffinTotalHeight{\OuterForestCoffin}-\CoffinTotalHeight{\InnerForestCoffin})+\CoffinHeight{\InnerForestCoffin})%
          },
        },
      },
    }%
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\bfseries,
  },
  delimit tree={\left\llbracket}{\right\rrbracket}
  [S
    [S
      [
        [NP
          [N
            [Ann]
          ]
        ]
        [VP
          [V
            [smokes]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [and]
    [S
      [
        [NP
          [N
            [John]
          ]
        ]
        [VP
          [V
            [drinks]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  delimit tree={\left\langle\left(}{\right)\right\rangle}
  [S
    [NP
      [N
        [Ann]
      ]
    ]
    [VP
      [V
        [smokes]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```