# Aligning material in delimiters within linguex examples

Tags: delimiters, tikz-qtree, linguex

I'm trying to put trees (drawn with tikz-qtree) inside interpretation function brackets (scaled to the tree as suggested here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133465) within a linguex example. Currently the trees-in-brackets are appearing in the center of the page; I would like them to appear the same distance from the example labels as material not surrounded by delimiters does.

[image: output of mwe]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. 
\[ \left \llbracket
\tikz[baseline={([yshift=+-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]{
\Tree [.S [.DP this tree ] [.VP is [.XP bracketed [.YP and centered ] ] ] ]
} \right \rrbracket\]

\ex. Look how close to the label non-arboreal examples are!

\ex. \Tree [.S [.DP this tree ] [.VP is [.XP unbracketed [.YP but in-the-right-place ] ] ] ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, replace \[ … \] with $ … $.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. That does correct the horizontal alignment (though it creates a new vertical alignment issue, which fortunately seems easier to fix).

Comment: In case you need to number your ‘equations’, you can use the `fleqn` environment , from `nccmath`,  which uses locally the `fleqn` option.