# variable-sized "such that" pipe

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a pipe symbol that can be made to vary in height automatically.

One of the common ways of writing "such that" in mathematics is with the pipe symbol (|). The pipe can be represented in LaTeX directly as the character | or as `\vert`, but neither of these expands vertically in math presentation mode. I can adjust it manually this way:

```
\[\mathcal{H}=\left\lbrace h(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_{i}x_{i}\mod m\ \Bigg\vert
     \ a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{m^{k}}\right\rbrace\]
```

[image: Using \Bigg\vert]

but I am looking for a true variable-sized option, parallel to `\lbrace` etc.

The `amsmath` package provides `\lvert` and `\rvert`, but I do not find them expanding as expected, and the `amsmath` documentation specifies that they should be used as binary delimiters (one on each side of something else), rather than alone.

Comment: As a side-note, rather use `\[ ... \]` for display math as opposed to `$$ ... $$`. See the [`l2tabu` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf).

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but (as you can seen in our answers) you really shouldn't use `$$ ... $$` for displayed math.  See [Why is \[ .. \] preferable to $$ .. $$](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2693)

Comment: @Werner, @Alan Munn, yes, I always use `\[ ... ]\`, but for some reason the code did not convert to mathematics and only the brackets were showing when I posted. So I thought I'd be safer with the `$$`. I'll change them back now, though.

Comment: not exactly relevant to the question asked, but what happened to the minus in the upper limit on the sum?

Comment: @barbara beeton: Not so nice-looking, right? I think I'm supposed to insert an "italic correction" (`\/`) there. But I didn't; lazy, no excuse, your forbearance please.

Comment: Note that `|` and `\vert` is not the correct way to write "such that" because they are not defined as binary relation symbols. The correct way is to use `\mid`. See also http://jblevins.org/notes/latex#conditioning and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vert-lvert-rvert/500#500

Comment: @brannerchinese -- it's not that it's not nice looking; it's the wrong shape (too short and a bit fat; it's a hyphen, not a minus).  take a look at the same symbol in the image in the answer by Alan Munn.  i'm having trouble trying to figure out how you got a hyphen, which is normally restricted to text mode, not math.  a coding incompatibility?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [`braket`](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) package for this kind of thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{H}=\Set{ h(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_{i}x_{i}\mod m\ |
     \ a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{m^{k}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

It defines a `\Set` macro which automatically puts its contents in variable sized braces, and any instance of the `|` symbol inside will adjust accordingly.  This solution also has the advantage of making your source code more semantic.

[image: output of code]

Comment: How about if there is a `|` symbol inside the set that denotes something else (e.g. conditional probability) and needs to be of normal size?

Comment: @3lectrologos In the `\Set` macro, only the first `|` encountered will be large; other ones will be regular size. If you need a `|` on the left hand side of the large vertical, you can use `\vert` or `\mid`. For conditional probability I would use `\mid`.

Answer (score 33):

You can also use `\middle` which goes with `\left` and `\right`:

```
\[
\mathcal{H}=\left\{ h(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_{i}x_{i}\mod m\ \middle|\ 
     a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{m^{k}}\right\}
\]
```

This saves you having to use `\left.` or `\right.` unnecessarily.

Comment: One might add that `\middle` is an e-TeX feature. (The solution by Alan Munn will rely on this when available.)

Comment: Ah, thank you - I had a vague recollection that this was a relatively recent feature but was mildly surprised to find I didn't need to load any packages to get this to work. That'll be why.

Answer (score 14):

You could use `\left| stuff \right.` or `\left. stuff \right|` depending on where you want the `|` and where it should take it's size from. For instance:

```
\[
  \left.\sum_{i \in I} x_i \right| x_i > 2
\]
```

takes the size from the sum. (Yes, I realize its a stupid example). Whereas

```
\[
  \sum_{i \in I} x_i \left| x_i > 2 \right.
\]
```

takes the size of the `x_i > 2`.

I see you added an example, that would become:

```
\[
  \mathcal{H}=\left\lbrace h(x)=\left.\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_{i}x_{i}\mod m\ \right|\ a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{m^{k}}\right\rbrace
\]
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to use the `|` in the following context: `\left\{x | \sum_i x >10\right\}` for example.

Comment: `\left\{x \left| \sum_i x >10\right.\right\}` will work fine if you want the `|` to be the size of the sum.

Comment: Ah you need a second `\right.` and it needs a dot. OK.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution with a syntax much closer to the mathematical meaning

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\providecommand\given{} % is redefined in \Set
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{\nonscript\:#1\vert \allowbreak\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]{\{}{\}}{
  \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
  #1
}
```

Now we can simply use

```
\Set{ x\in A \given x^2 > 1 }
```

much much closer to the mathematical meaning.

In the OPs case, I'd use

```
\Set[\Big]{ h(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_{i}x_{i}\mod m \given  a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{m^{k}} }
```

as there is no reason to scale the fences excessively.

I use the separate `\SetSymbol` macro, because there are very complicated set constructions, where one cannot use `\Set` (as in `\{` and `\}` on separate lines), and thus in that case one may want to be able to refer to the given symbol for sets, just in case one want change the symbol later on.

Update: March 2015, added `\mathopen{}` and `\allowbreak`