# How can I make a long pipe in mathmode for sets?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [variable-sized “such that” pipe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/variable-sized-such-that-pipe)

I currently have this LaTeX code:

```
\text{Aff}(M) := \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i p_i | p_i \in M, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K}, \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1\right \}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

But I would like to get a long pipe for my set, not this "|" short one. How can I make it long?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\middle|`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{Aff}(M) := \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i p_i \, \middle| \, p_i \in M, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K}, \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1\right \}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the two fine spaces I introduced (before and after the vertical bar) and the change from `\text` to `\mathrm`.

If instead of the `\left\{...\right\}` delimiters, some of the commands in the `\big..., \Big...` family is being used, then one can use the corresponding `\bigm,\Bigm,...` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\bigm\lvert\quad\Bigm\lvert\quad\biggm\lvert\quad\Biggm\lvert$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work in Wikipedia. But I've found this work-around: $\mathrm{Aff}(M) := \left \{\left. \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i p_i \ \right|\  p_i \in M, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K}, \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1\right \}$

Comment: Somebody mentioned that I should not use `\text{}` and nod `\mathrm{}` but `\operatorname{}`.

Comment: @moose that depends on whether you want "Aff" to behave as an operator or not.

Comment: The answer with `$\bigm\lvert\quad\Bigm\lvert\quad\biggm\lvert\quad\Biggm\lvert$` works with markups in Jupyter.

Answer (score 7):

The [`braket` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) provides this functionality for creating sets using the notation `\Set{...|...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}% http://ctan.org/pkg/braket

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{Aff}(M) := \Set{ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i p_i | 
  p_i \in M, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K}, \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1 }$

\end{document}​
```