# How to do multiple lines within braces?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I was wondering what the proper LaTeX code would be to display something like this:

[image]

You don't have to include the mathematical symbols, what is important is the structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the multi-row contents using an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\[
  A = \left\{ b\ \middle\vert \begin{array}{l}
    C, d \\
    e, F, g
  \end{array}\right\}
\]

% Using braket; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32051/5764
\[
  A = \Set{ b\ | \begin{array}{l}
    C, d \\
    e, F, g
  \end{array}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you reckon is the difference between the two, except for the fact that the second approach requires the "braket" package? The second one also looks like it has a bit wider space around the middle line.

Comment: How do you obtain the high resolution images above?

Comment: @index: That's about it. It's always best to [define some macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) when you're doing something regularly, for consistency. That's why [`braket`](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) would be a good idea.

Comment: @gernot: I view the output in a PDF viewer where I can then zoom in (if needed). Then I take a screen grab of the portion of interest and copy-and-paste that as an image upload. Not sure how you go about with your lower-resolution image uploads.

Comment: Taking a screenshot works also in my case, great idea!

Answer (score 4):

You should define a unique structure for this kind of objects and I propose a variant of the `\Set` command described in the documentation of `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}

\providecommand\given{} % ensure it exists
\newcommand\givensymbol[1]{%
  \nonscript\;\delimsize#1\allowbreak\nonscript\;\mathopen{}%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{%
  \renewcommand\given{\givensymbol{\vert}}%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\Set{x\given y} \\
\Set[\big]{x\given (a+b)c} \\
\Set*{z \given
  \begin{aligned}
  & 1\le z_{(k,m)}^{l}\le 1+a_{(k,m)}^{l}\gamma_{(k,m)}^{l}(\bm{p}) \\
  & \forall k\in\mathcal{K}, \forall m\in\mathcal{M},
    \forall l\in\mathcal{L}, \forall\bm{a}\in\mathcal{A}^{\dagger},
    \forall \bm{p}\in\mathcal{P}
  \end{aligned}
}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So this uses "aligned" rather than "array"? Are there any consequental differences between your approach and the other ones described above?

Comment: @index This approach is independent on what you put right of the bar. You can add anything, small or big: just set suitably the optional argument to `\Set` (`\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`) or use `*` for automatic sizing if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{Z}=\left\{
z \biggm| \begin{array}{l}
1\leq\\
\forall k
\end{array}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe, that there should be `\biggm|`, not simply `\bigg|`, giving the proper space. (Observe `\middle\vert`, not `\vert`, in Werner's answer).