# Center contents of set definition left of | (one line) with contents right of | (multiple lines) with large |, {, and }

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, align, braces

Basically, I'm trying to get my set definition to look exactly like the image.

But when I do \Set{w \in { 0,1 } \mid (long definition) }, the text just goes off the right edge of the page and neither the brackets nor the | adjust to fit the long contents.[image]

Comment: You can use a simple `\parbox{width}{text}`

Comment: Did you see [How to do multiple lines within braces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329170)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, with a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\left\{
w \in \{0,1\}^* \,\middle|\,
\stackanchor{there is a way to insert the substring 011 (once) into $w$}
{so that the result is a multiple of 3 in binary}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]