# How to write norm which adjusts its size?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need to write norm of sum, but the sum symbol is larger than tho norm symbol (||) and it doesn't look good. Is there any symbol for norm which will adjust its size?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
   \begin{document}  
    \begin{equation}
     ||\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \bf P_{\rm n}\rm\right) ||^2 = \left(\sum_n \frac{E_n}{c}\right)^2 - \left(\sum_n \bf p_{\rm n}\rm \right)^2   
    \end{equation}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Please, use `\mathbf{P}_{n}` and don't use `\rm` or `\bf` any more: they have been obsolete for more than ten years in LaTeX.

Answer (score 130):

Either of the following methods should work:

- You could load the `amsmath` package and define a `\norm` macro as follows:

  ```
  \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
  ```

  and then write

  ```
  \norm{ \biggl(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf{P}_{n}\biggr) }
  ```

  in the equation of interest. Note that the round parentheses will be too big if you write `\left(` and `\right)`; I recommend you write `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` instead.

  Your example code may therefore be written as

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
  \begin{document}  
    \begin{equation}
      \norm{ \biggl(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf{P}_{n}\biggr) }^2 = 
             \biggl(\sum_n \frac{E_n}{c}\biggr)^2 - 
             \biggl(\sum_n \mathbf{p}_{n} \biggr)^2   
    \end{equation}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

- Some might say that the resulting norm "fences" in the example above are a bit too large and thus threaten to dominate visually the rest of the math stuff. (This happens, of course, because the macro uses `\left` and `\right` directives to size the fences.) To fix this issue, you could load the `mathtools` package and insert the following instruction in the preamble:

  ```
  \DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\lVert}{\rVert}{#1}
  ```

  and use the `\norm` macro with an explicit size instruction (here: `\bigg`, i.e., the same size as for the parentheses):

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\lVert}{\rVert}{#1}
  \begin{document} 
    \begin{equation}
      \norm[\bigg]{\biggl(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf{P}_{n}\biggr) }^2 = 
                   \biggl(\sum_n \frac{E_n}{c}\biggr)^2 - 
                   \biggl(\sum_n \mathbf{p}_{n} \biggr)^2   
    \end{equation}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why `\lvert` and `\rvert` should be preferred over `\|`?

Comment: take a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vertical-bar-vert-lvert-rvert-divides)

Comment: @VincentNivoliers - Note that `\Vert` is equivalent to `\|`. The `l` and `r` prefixes inform TeX that the commands `\lVert` and `\rVert` should be given math codes `mathopen` and `mathclose`, respectively. (TeX has no way of knowing how to modify the default math code of `\Vert`.)

Comment: Any reason why `\norm` is not pre-defined in `amsmath` or some other package? It is a quite common operation.

Comment: @juliohm - Questions about *why* some feature may be present or absent from any particular LaTeX package should be addressed to the package's maintainer(s).

Comment: This does not work for me, produces product signs...

Comment: @PascalIv - I am very confident that the code shown in my answer does *not* produce product symbols. Now, my mind-reading skills have always been, currently are, and always will be *absolutely worthless*.  Therefore, unless *you* tell me what *you* are actually doing, the likelihood that I'll somehow manage to figure out what could be going on in your LaTeX code that could be poducing product symbols is *exactly zero*. So, do please divulge a bit more information about what you're doing.

Comment: @Mico - I am sorry, sometimes Latex frustration before a deadline makes me post a useless comment. I use beamer, have a lot of imports and \lVert, \| etc. produces large Pi/product signs. Was hoping someone maybe saw this before and knows which import messes things up.

Comment: @PascalIv - If I replace `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` with `\documentclass{beamer}`, the document still doesn't produce product symbols instead of summation symbols. All I can surmise is that one or more of the packages you're loading (I have no idea which one it could be... -- cf. my earlier comment) would appear to be messing with the meaning of `\sum`.

Answer (score 66):

Use `\Vert` instead of `||`. You can prefix `\Vert` with any brace-sizing-command, like `\left`, `\right`, `\big`, ..

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\begin{document}  
    \begin{equation}
        \left\Vert\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \bf P_{\rm n}\rm\right) \right\Vert^2 = \left(\sum_n \frac{E_n}{c}\right)^2 - \left(\sum_n \bf p_{\rm n}\rm \right)^2   
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you want a more 'polished' look for a special case, just look around and search for `absolute value`. There are many questions here (like [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols)) which provide additional information, if you want to know more `;)`

Comment: All the `\rm` commands used are wrong: besides being an obsolete command, the `n` should be in italics. Also `\bf` is obsolete, use `\mathbf{P}` and `\mathbf{p}`.

Comment: @egreg: Suzie wrote the `n` in `E_n` in italics, so I think it was a choice to typeset the `n` in `P_n` in an upright shape.

Comment: @ralfix According to mathematical conventions, an italic and an upright "n" don't necessarily denote the same object. My feeling is that `\rm` has been used in order to countermand `\bf`, but it's wrong to begin with.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, the \mathbf{} is really great. Now my work looks much better :)