# How to type rectangle norm symbol in math?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, math-operators

How can I write the rectangular norm symbol in `math-mode` where the text in between is centered, as seen hereinafter?

[image: rectangle norm symbol]

Comment: Welcome. Perhaps the discussion here [link to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107186/how-to-write-norm-which-adjusts-its-size) might be useful?

Comment: Much attention, vertical closed rectangle norm. Thank you Steven Hodgkinson. Help! :)

Comment: Thank you  Stefan Pinnow, for edit and write correctly my post question.

Comment: The STIX fonts have `\talloblong` and `\bigtalloblong`, but no extensible delimiter. Are you planning to use this symbol in various sizes?

Comment: To voters: the suggested duplicate is wrong as it doesn't address in any way the problem at hand.

Comment: @egreg, er would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson There are pending “close as duplicate” votes, but the suggested duplicate doesn't really address the present problem.

Comment: @MartinSchröder perhaps I'm guilty of not linking back to the original post [Absolute value Symbols] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols) but the OP asked about the norm symbol and that's something different (both symbol wise and also what it represents). Hence, the link I provided illustrated how one might reproduce a norm symbol. Hence I linked to a post that dealt with that question.

Comment: @egreg -- do you believe that there is a need for extensible "talloblongs"?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've never seen such a notation for a norm. Maybe Deisy can add some reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\newcommand*\recnrm[1]{\left[\!\left]#1\right[\!\right]}
```

It's a first step, that can be “tweaked” but the important part is that you use a command `\recnrm{x}` or `\recnrm{\frac{A}{B}}`. Then you can change the definition later.

Comment: Nice!, Thank you! Manuel. 
Already I made changes to the code in latex, and run.

Comment: The way to say thanks in this site is upvoting if you think an answer is useful, and accepting the answer that most benefited you. In any case, if you want to tweak the “width” of the delimiters, I could add a version where `\!` is substituted by a defined `\mspace{-0.2ex}` with predefined widths.