# Norm with adjustable size?

Tags: math-mode

There was a [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107186/how-to-write-norm-which-adjusts-its-size) question asked some time back. The solutions was to use the package `amsmath` and define `norm` as

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
```

However, I am using the packages `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` and it is advised not to amsmath with them. How can I then achieve a re-scaled norm sign in LaTeX?

Comment: Why not `amsmath`? I suppose you mean `amsfonts` or `amssymb`?

Comment: `amsmath` is loaded by `newpxmath`, but following the advice on the linked page, if i define the `norm` as `\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}`, I get the error that it is already defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend defining them via the `mathtools` package using

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
```

Then

```
\norm{x}    =  \lVert x \rVert
\norm*{x}   = \left\lVert x \right\rVert
\norm[\Big] = \Bigl\lVert x \Bigr\rVert
```

For more information see the `mathtools` manual

Note that it is generally not recommended to have autoscaling as the default, only use autoscaling in those explicit instances you need it. (I personally use it very rarely in my manuscript edits)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`): adding this code in your preamble:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert
```

defines a `\norm`  command and a starred version `\norm*`, which adds a pair of implicit `\left ... \right` in front of the delimiters. For fine-tuning the delimiters size, the unstarred version accepts an optional argument: `\norm[\big]`, or `[\Big], [\bigg], [\Bigg]`, which adds a pair of implicit `\bigl ... \bigr`, &c., in front of the delimiters.