# Undefined control sequence \nmid

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I need to express that "a is not divisible by b" in my LaTeX document. It is my understanding that I should use the `\nmid` symbol for this case, as in `$b \nmid a$`.

LaTeX gives me the following error: `Undefined control sequence`. The `\mid` symbol works fine. I have imported the `amsmath` package via the following command: `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: Zdravím, Dušane, přesně jak říká @egreg, tohle je v `amssymb`, ne v `amsmath`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117032/divides-not-divides-and-cardinalities

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html gives you command/symbol and package that supports it.