# Putting \not before \big| when using "mathabx" package

Tags: symbols, mathabx

`\not|` works well, but `\not\big|` not. I have also tried `\centernot` instead of `\not` without success.

**Edit:**
This is the minimal document producing the problem.

**Edit2:** I use `mathabx` package to have the things like `\widecheck`, `\nequiv` and some other symbols. But I would like to use `\big|` and `\not\big|` at the same time. It seems that `mathabx` causes conflict.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
$\not\big|$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this works for me. Please post a MWE with the minimal code that did not work.

Comment: @TeXnician i provided a mwe.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117032/divides-not-divides-and-cardinalities

Comment: Do you really use the symbols `|`, `\big|`, `\not|`, and `\not{\big|}` all in the same document? Are you sure your readers can pick up the difference between `|` and `\big|`?

Comment: @Mico I have many expressions like `|A| | |B|` and would like to use `|A| \big| |B|` to distinguish between the sign of  "divides" and that of `carnality`. I know there are other variants such as `\mid`, `\divides`, but I really prefer `\big|`. The only problem is that I would also like to adapt this for "not-dividing", hence my question.

Answer (score 3):

A  bunch of solutions with `stackengine`:  I defined `\big, Big, &c.` variants in two series, based on `\varnot + \vert` or on `\ndivides + \vert` with a different `\not` sign.  I suppose it is intended to be a (non-)relational symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, mathabx, xcolor}

\usepackage{stackengine, relsize}
\newcommand{\nmid}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-1.24ex}{c}{}{\varnot}{\vert}}}
\newcommand{\nbmid}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-1.24ex}{c}{}{\varnot}{\big\vert}}}
\newcommand{\nBmid}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-1.24ex}{c}{}{\varnot}{\Big\vert}}}
\newcommand{\nbbmid}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-1.24ex}{c}{}{\varnot}{\bigg\vert}}}
\newcommand{\nBBmid}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-1.24ex}{c}{}{\varnot}{\Bigg\vert}}}
%%%
\newcommand{\bndivides}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-0.325ex}{c}{}{\notdivides}{\big\vert}}}
\newcommand{\Bndivides}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-0.32ex}{c}{}{\notdivides}{\Big\vert}}}
\newcommand{\bbndivides}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-0.32ex}{c}{}{\notdivides}{\bigg\vert}}}
\newcommand{\BBndivides}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-0.32ex}{c}{}{\notdivides}{\Bigg\vert}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}{l*{6}{c}}
\verb+ \nmid series: + & \nmid & \nbmid & \nBmid & \nbbmid & \nBBmid \\[4ex]
\verb+ \ndivides series: + & \ndivides & \bndivides & \Bndivides & \bbndivides & \BBndivides
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work.

Comment: @Mico: It's only althe initial suggestion which didn't work with `mathabx`. I've replaced it with a working code.

Comment: Does it means that it is impossible to use $\not\big|$ and `mathabx` simultaneously?

Comment: Well, it seems so. I don't know why. Note thet you use `mathabx` only for a few symbols, you can declare these symbols without having to load the whole font.