# How can I align this sequence of equalities and inequalities?

Tags: math-mode, align

Everything I find only deals with `=` signs and not with `\le` and `<`.

```
$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)+f_n(y)-f(y)| 
             \le |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)| 
             < \epsilon/3+\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3 
             = \epsilon$
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What should be aligned to what? Please don't show only a code snippet. Always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) from `\documentclass` down to `\end{document}` that illustrates your problem. And also describe your problem. Without it's hard to reproduce and understand the problem. Inline math (`$`…`$`) is usually unaligned. Do you want displayed math with multiple lines?

Comment: note that texworks is unrelated to the problem, that is the editor you are using to write the tex, but it would be the same if you used any other editor.

Answer (score 6):

Everything you found explaining how to align equality signs works the same way for every other symbol, letter or number. Just put an `&` before the symbols that you want to align on. For your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert &= \lvert f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)+f_n(y)-f(y)\rvert \\
    &\le \lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert+\lvert f_n(x)-f_n(y)\rvert+\lvert f_n(y)-f(y)\rvert \\
    &< \epsilon/3+\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3 \\
    &= \epsilon
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note: Since you are using the vertical bar as a delimiter here, you might want to use `\lvert` and `\rvert` instead of `|`. See e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518/103046) for a discussion.

Comment: In a case like this, I’d rather go for a `split` environment.  Also, I’d use `\lvert ... \rvert`, or, perhaps, `\bigl| ... \bigr|`.