# "Missing $ inserted" error when using "cases" inside an equation environment

Tags: cases, mathtools

I have the following piece of latex code

```
\begin{equation*}
    G(z,w) =
    \begin{cases*}
      \frac{\rho (g_{\bar{\lambda}}(z),g_{\bar{\lambda}}(w))}{\rho (z,w)} & for z \neq w \\
      |f'|_{\rho} & for z = w
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation*}
```

and i keep getting `missing $` and `missing }` errors. From what I've read most commonly these are caused by putting `$` inside the `equation` environment (which is redundant) or leaving an empty line inside mat mode. As far as I can tell I'm not doing either, and I can't figure out what is wrong with this formula. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there a reason for using a `cases*` environment instead of a `cases` environment?

Comment: @Mico Ok that was it, embarassingly I completely missed that. The error message led me to believe it would have to be something else. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Related, if you're expecting that the second column is already in math mode, then you should use `\text{for }` to avoid "for" being in math mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume that you're trying to uses the `cases*` environment that's provided by the `mathtools` package. If this assumption is *not* correct, please let me know.

The `cases*` environment, unlike the `cases` environment, assumes that the material in the second column, i.e., after the `&` character, is in text mode. Since there's is a `\neq` macro in the first line, LaTeX complains since `\neq` must occur in math mode.

The remedy: Replace the strings `z \neq w` and `z = w` with `$z \neq w$` and `$z = w$`, respectively.

You may also want to replace the `cases*` environment with `dcases*` so that the fraction term in the first row is typeset in display-style math mode instead of in text-style math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'cases*' and 'dcases*' environments
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
G(z,w)
 &= \begin{cases*}
      \frac{\rho (g_{\bar{\lambda}}(z),g_{\bar{\lambda}}(w))}{\rho (z,w)} & for $z \neq w$ \\
      |f'|_{\rho} & for $z = w$
    \end{cases*}\\[2ex]
 &= \begin{dcases*}
      \frac{\rho (g_{\bar{\lambda}}(z),g_{\bar{\lambda}}(w))}{\rho (z,w)} & for $z \neq w$ \\
      |f'|_{\rho} & for $z = w$
    \end{dcases*}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The second column of the `cases*` environment is set up to contain text, so you'll need to  enclose the math contents in that column in `$…$`. (See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) of the `mathtools` package, which is where `cases*` is defined.)

The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    G(z,w) =
    \begin{cases*}
      \frac{\rho (g_{\bar{\lambda}}(z),g_{\bar{\lambda}}(w))}{\rho (z,w)} & for $z \neq w$ \\
      \lvert f'\rvert_{\rho} & for $z = w$
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

Note:
In addition to inserting the aforementioned `$…$` I also replaced `|f'|` by `\lvert f'\rvert` The difference is that `\lvert` and `\rvert` have the spacing of an opening/closing bracket respectively. See .e.g the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498/156366).